# how to check the creation date of tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

The question is:

List of the `DW1_ tables` from the `USER_OBJECTS` with table names, creation date and time in ISO standard.

that's what I have so far, but it does not work.

```
select table_name, to_char(create_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') from all_tables 
where table_name like 'DW1%'
group by table_name;
```

It said create_date is invalid identifier.

Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: Create Date is not a field in all_tables from my understanding...

Comment: should be from user_objects not all_tables, but I still dont know which method I could use here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442323/how-to-find-out-when-a-particular-table-was-created-in-oracle

Comment: select object_name, to_char(created, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "Creation date" from user_objects 
where object_name like 'DW1%';         thx everyone anyways

Comment: If you're looking for table names that begin with "DW1_", what you need is: table_name like 'DW1\_%' escape '\'

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select object_name, created 
from user_objects 
where object_name LIKE 'DW1%' 
    and object_type = 'TABLE';
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c9a3/1)

Comment: Why do I prefer this answer, using `user_objects`, compared to those using `dba_objects`? Because often there are no read permissions on `dba_objects`, but on `user_objects`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select object_name, to_char(created, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS created -- 'AS' is optional
  from user_objects 
 where object_name like 'EMP%' -- replace with your table
/
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT object_name tablename, created FROM dba_objects
WHERE object_name like 'DW1%'
and object_type = 'TABLE'
```